# What is the convention for method chaining with lambda parameters?

Tags: lambda, kotlin

I was working on a Kotlin coding challenge and I came up with a solution that looks something like this:

```
val x = listOf(1, 2, 3)
    .fold("") { acc, i ->
      acc + someLookupFunction(i)
    }.let {
      // something
    }
```

Above is how I expect it to be formatted. However, when using the IntelliJ auto-formatter, it insists that the code should be formatted like so:

```
val x = listOf(1, 2, 3)
    .fold("") { acc, i ->
      acc + someLookupFunction(i)
    }.let {
          // something
        }
```

My first thought was that this is a bug, but actually I think it's just ambiguous. The formatter must think that the `let` is a function call on the lambda itself, not on the result of `fold`. To confirm this, I changed it to this:

```
val x = listOf(1, 2, 3)
    .fold("", { acc, i ->
      acc + someLookupFunction(i)
    }).let {
      // something
    }
```

and Intellij formatted it how I expect. So that brings me to my question - is there an official convention on chaining method calls when using lambdas like this? Should I be using the explicit parens when chaining to avoid ambiguity? Is this actually a bug with Intellij that I should report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Kotlin documentation has a section on coding styles, including [this on chained-call wrapping](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#chained-call-wrapping):

> Chained call wrapping
>
> When wrapping chained calls, put the . character or the ?. operator on the next line, with a single indent:
>
> ```
> val anchor = owner
>     ?.firstChild!!
>     .siblings(forward = true)
>     .dropWhile { it is PsiComment || it is PsiWhiteSpace }
> ```
>
> The first call in the chain usually should have a line break before it, but it's OK to omit it the code makes more sense that way.

So I would probably alter it like so:

```
  val x = listOf(1, 2, 3)
      .fold("") { acc, i ->
          acc + someLookupFunction(i)
      }
      .let {
          // something
      }
```

Or:

```
val x = listOf(1, 2, 3)
    .fold("") { acc, i -> acc + someLookupFunction(i) }
    .let { /* something */ }
```

Comment: I see, that makes sense. IntelliJ seems to handle that first case a little better at least. I actually wound up submitting a bug to Jetbrains because while investigating, I found some other inconsistent behavior. But for the context of the question, this seems pretty conclusive.

Answer (score 1):

The proposed formatting by IntelliJ is correct because when a lambda is the last parameter of a function, the lambda can be extracted out of the parenthesis of the method.

So IntelliJ does not think that `let` is a function call on the lambda itself, it's just another way of writing the same code as what you would expect (your 3rd snippet).

From [Kotlin official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html) :

> In Kotlin, there is a convention that if the last parameter to a function is a function, and you're passing a lambda expression as the corresponding argument, you can specify it outside of parentheses. [...] These conventions allow to write LINQ-style code:
>
> `strings.filter { it.length == 5 }.sortedBy { it }.map { it.toUpperCase() }`